# Division of two dataframe with Group by of a Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe df_F1:

```
df_F1.info()
```

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
> Data columns (total 7 columns):
> class_energy              2 non-null object
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1    2 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3    2 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5    2 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8    2 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7    2 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8    2 non-null float64
> dtypes: float64(6), object(1)
> memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
> ```

```
 df_F1.head()
```

> ```
> class_energy ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5 
> low 5.875550 431.000000 856.666667 
> medium 856.666667 856.666667 856.666667
> ```

I try to create a dataframe Ratio which contain for each class_energy the value of energy of each ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_Fx divided by the sum of energy of all ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_Fx.
For example:

```
          ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3 ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5
low        5.875550/(5.875550 + 431.000000+856.666667) 431.000000/(5.875550+431.000000+856.666667) 856.666667/(5.875550+431.000000+856.666667)
medium     856.666667/(856.666667+856.666667+856.666667) 856.666667/(856.666667+856.666667+856.666667) 856.666667/(856.666667+856.666667+856.666667)
```

Any idea please to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`DF.divide`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html) to divide the required columns with their `sum` along the same columns as shown:

```
df.iloc[:,1:4] = df.iloc[:,1:4].divide(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print(df)

  class_energy  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1  ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3  \
0          low                0.004542                0.333194   
1       medium                0.333333                0.333333   

   ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5  
0                0.662264  
1                0.333333
```

Comment: when I do df_Ratio = df_F1.loc[:,"ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1":"ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5"] = df_F1.loc[:,"ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1":"ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5"].divide(df_F1.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
I get a dataframe without class_energy column,  do you know why?

Comment: That is because you are only using a subset of the entire `dataframe` and making changes to those values only. If you want `df_ratio` to include all the columns, you could assign it as `df_ratio=df_F1`. And now, `df_ratio` gets all the columns which `df_F1` had before.